# Validación datetimepicker con librería Bootstrap Validator

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo dos datetimepicker uno que selecciona un mes y otro que selecciona un año, estoy validando que no estén vacíos o tengan el formato para mes 'MM' y para año 'YYYY' pero en el formato de la fecha pareciera incorrecta por que lo valida como incorrecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi js es

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setStartDate', '2016')
        //$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setStartDate', '2012-01-01');

        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepickerMes').datetimepicker({
                //viewMode: 'Months',
                format: 'MM',
                locale: 'es'
            });

            $('#datetimepickerAnio').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'YYYY',
                minDate: '01/01/2016'
            });
        });


        $('#registrationForm').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {

                datetimepickerMes: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser vacia'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'MM',
                            message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no es valida'
                        }
                    }
                },

                datetimepickerAnio: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser vacia'
                        },
                        date: {
                            format: 'YYYY',
                            message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no es valida'
                        }
                    }
                },

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que en el [`date`](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/date/#options) validator los tokens `YYYY` y `DD` también son obligatorios por lo que no te funcionará si la validación que tratas de configurar no incluye `DD` , `MM` y `YYYY`, todos juntos.

Las dos opciones que tienes aquí son:

1. Usar un [regexp](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/regexp/) validator

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#registrationForm').bootstrapValidator({
       feedbackIcons: {
         valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
         invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
         validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
       },
       fields: {

         datetimepickerMes: {
           validators: {
             notEmpty: {
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser vacia'
             },
             regexp: {
               regexp: /^(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])$/,
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no es valida'
             }
           }
         },

         datetimepickerAnio: {
           validators: {
             notEmpty: {
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser vacia'
             },
             regexp: {
               regexp: /^\d{4}$/,
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no es valida'
             }
           }
         },

       }
     });
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>


   <form id="registrationForm" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Fecha</label>

       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control date" name="datetimepickerMes" placeholder="Mes" />
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datetimepickerAnio" placeholder="Año" />
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```

   2. Usar un [callback](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/validators/callback/) validator

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#registrationForm').bootstrapValidator({
       feedbackIcons: {
         valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
         invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
         validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
       },
       fields: {

         datetimepickerMes: {
           validators: {
             notEmpty: {
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser vacia'
             },
             callback: {
               callback: function(value, validator) {
                 var m = new moment(value, 'MM', true);
                 return m.isValid()
               },
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no es valida'
             }
           }
         },

         datetimepickerAnio: {
           validators: {
             notEmpty: {
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no puede ser vacia'
             },
             callback: {
               callback: function(value, validator) {
                 var m = new moment(value, 'YYYY', true);
                 return m.isValid()
               },
               message: 'La fecha de nacimiento no es valida'
             }
           }
         },

       }
     });
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>


   <form id="registrationForm" class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Fecha</label>

       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control date" name="datetimepickerMes" placeholder="Mes" />
       </div>

       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datetimepickerAnio" placeholder="Año" />
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```

En mi opinión la primer opción es la mejor ya que es la mas sencilla y fácil de configurar pero te puse la otra también en caso que tengas que hacer alguna comprobación más complicada. Suerte